# Error casting from Int to Double

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand why casting in the first case works while in the second it fails.  What is the difference between the two?

```
var myVariable = 2

var myDoubleTest1 = Double(myVariable)
var myDoubleTest2 = myVariable as? Double

print(myDoubleTest1)  // 2.0
print(myDoubleTest2)  // nil
```

Comment: So casting is used when casting variables of the same type.... for example when I segue....let controller = segue.destination as! ItemDetailViewController.  ItemDetailViewController is a UIViewController so this is a cast, rather than a conversion?  And a conversion is changing the type of the variable?  Yes?

Comment: yes as? for same types , not conversion from type to type , so when use as! it will crash the app for different types

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Please delete both of your comments since they are not correct at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myDoubleTest1 = Double(myVariable)
```

This line is just an initializer on `Double`. It takes an int, and initializes a new double. The documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1538399-init).

```
var myDoubleTest2 = myVariable as? Double
```

The `as?` keyword in Swift performs a **cast**. This means, in English, "create a variable named `myDoubleTest2`. If `myVariable` is of type `Double`, then use that. Otherwise, make it `nil`. We know, from the first line in your code (`var myVariable = 2`), that **`myVariable` is not a Double (it is an Int)**, so `myDoubleTest2` will be `nil`. You can read more about type casting [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

Answer (score 1):

The first case

```
var myDoubleTest1 = Double(myVariable)
```

you actually converts the Int to Double

but in second

```
var myDoubleTest2 = myVariable as? Double
```

it checks whether `myVariable`  is of Double type & has no nil value if passed ,it assigns it's value to `myDoubleTest2`

Comment: The first line does not _convert_ the Int to a Double. It initializes a new Double with the given value. The Int variable is not changed.

Comment: didn't not said that the int variable will be affected , i mean it's value will be converted and assigned to the lhs